# Play .mp4 video in a .NET Windows forms application

Tags: .net, forms, mp4

I would like to play a .mp4 file. I was using the following code to play a .wmv file using Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback but it crashes when I switch to the .mp4 file format.

```
Video v;
v = Video.FromFile("C:\\sample_mpeg4.mp4");
v.Owner = pbMain;
v.Play();
```

Is there a simple way to get the .mp4 movie file playing?

Comment: Did you tried with the media player activex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this answer to a similar question: [Windows (ideally .NET callable) API to join MP4 and/or 3GP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207987/windows-ideally-net-callable-api-to-join-mp4-and-or-3gp-files)

After a bit of searching I can't find a list of supported formats for the **Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlaytback** library, thought the FFMPEG libraries should do the job as well as anything else out there.